# interactive dropdown menu in Rmarkdown/Quarto html document

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have an Rmarkdown document (html output) that presents the results of an analysis for a given dataset. I would like expand the document to have the results of the same analysis on n datasets. Ideally, the user would be able to select a single dataset by selecting values from several dropdown menus (that collectively specify a single dataset), then the html page would show the analysis results for that dataset. Basically, it would be equivalent to having the analysis on each dataset in its own tab or page, but instead of showing all the tabs/pages, I want several dropdown menus that allow the user to specify a single dataset and then only show a single page with the results of that dataset.

Rmarkdown [recommends using Shiny](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_interactive.html) for interactivity.

Quarto [recommends several options](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/), but I'm not sure if I can do what I want without using Shiny. Quarto will also soon have [dashboards](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/), which I think will allow for the sort of interactivity that I'm looking for, but I would like the output to be an HTML document, and I do not have access to a version of Quarto that has dashboards (i.e. 1.4+).